# Machine inaccessible in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Guest OS: Windows XP

Host OS: Windows 7

I suddenly cannot access one of my virtual machines in VirtualBox. And I don't remember having deleted one of the files necessary for it to run.

Comment: It looks as though the `.xml` configuration file may be missing or corrupt. Can you confirm that the file exists, and is accessible from the path shown in the screenshot?

Comment: yep its still there but its 0kb in size, see the edit

Comment: I still have the .vdi file. I'll just restore it using the vdi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the VM (but not its hard-disk file, when you're given the option.) Create a new VM and attach the existing hard disk file instead of creating a new HDD, and you should be good to go.